# Android Touch EventListener firing Callback more than once

Tags: android, event-handling, touch-event

I have attached a touch event listener with an ImageView  object,

```
imageview_obj.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
            Log.i(" info "," message");                        
            return true;
        }
     });
```

The problem is When I touch the imageview_obj, the callback is getting triggered more than once (3times to 4 times)..

Now my questions are

1. Why the callback getting triggered more than once?
2. How should I attach the onTouchListener so that I will be triggered once per touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was triggered on multiple actions because touch events has many like down, up and move etc event time so you need to implement this with specific event like down time or up time

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action){

        case Down_Action: // MotionEvent class field 
        Log.i(" info "," message");      
        break;
        case Up_Action:
        Log.i(" info "," message");      
        break;
        case Move_action:
        Log.i(" info "," message");      
        break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 imageview_obj.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
                Log.i(" info "," message");                        
                return true;
                  switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//Do code here for down
               return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//Do code here for up
            return true;
                 }
            }
         });
```